# How to dynamically sort a field in c# with mongo query syntax

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, c#-9.0

I am new to MongoDB. so I can able to do sorting in c# and linq format.
Butnot able to do in mongosyntax the whole idea is I am writing a mongo shell query, the same syntax I want to use in my c# code as well.

Here
****Method1:Not working****

```
  public async List<T> getGridData(Filter filter,sort sort,int page size,int currentPage){
    await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<Student>.Empty)
        .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
        .Limit(pageSize)
        .Sort("{LastName: 1}")   **// here it is static i want to pass dynaimc column name instead of last name**
        .ForEachAsync(
            student =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"S/N: {count}, \t Id: {student.Id}, FirstName: {student.FirstName}, LastName: {student.LastName}, Age: {student.Age}");
                count++;
            });
    
    }
```

Here i can use the mongo syntax but column name is hard coded like last

```
Ascending:
 .Sort("{LastName: 1}") I need to change  .Sort("{sort.columnName: 1}") 
Descending:
 .Sort("{LastName: -1}") I need to change  .Sort("{sort.columnName: -1}") but it detects as string.
```

which is the current column name.
****Method 2: // which is working fine****
I had achieved the same thing in C# driver mongo syntax;

```
await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<Student>.Empty)
    .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
    .Limit(pageSize)
    .Sort(Builders<Student>.Sort.Descending(sort.ColumnName))
    .ForEachAsync(
        student =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"S/N: {count}, \t Id: {student.Id}, FirstName: {student.FirstName}, LastName: {student.LastName}, Age: {student.Age}");
            count++;
        });
```

else  i can also achieve  by using the same syntax:
**MEthod 3:// which is working fine**

```
await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<Student>.Empty)
    .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
    .Limit(pageSize)
    .Sort(Builders<Student>.SortByDescending(x => nameof(sort.columnName))
    .ForEachAsync(
        student =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"S/N: {count}, \t Id: {student.Id}, FirstName: {student.FirstName}, LastName: {student.LastName}, Age: {student.Age}");
            count++;
        });
```

But the whole idea How I can get pass the  dynamic column in method 1 syntax which mongo shell scripting syntax

Comment: why not just do `.Sort($"{{{sort.columnName}: {sort.order}}}")`

Comment: i just tried `.Sort("${sort.columnName}: {sort.order}") ` - but it not worked , now i understood the syntax thanks for valuable answers .

Comment: do you see a difference between my string and yours? just copy-paste mine and check. it works.

Comment: Yes thanks it works ,thats what i mentioned in above comment